# Is there a substitution for C#'s await in C++/CX?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I'll try to keep the case as general as possible here: I'm writing a C++/CX application for Windows Phone 8.1 that manages a state, which is being changed in reaction to input coming, in turns, from different sources (e.g. app UI or network). I want to utilize an approach with a program loop that will, for each source, wait for input from it and then modify the state accordingly. The problem I'm having is that I could not find a good way to mirror the behavior of the await mechanism in C++/CX. Tasks seem to be the way to handle asynchronous data processing in C++/CX, but as far as I understand they are used for waiting for results of a well-defined operation, whereas I need to wait for an asynchronous event to happen and then act appropriately depending on the type of the event.

1. Is there an appropriate language construct, or a way to utilize tasks, to be used in this case?
2. Should I make use of basic multi-threading mechanisms, like semaphores, instead?
3. Alternatively, should I abandon this approach and handle state changes with events, securing the state from being otherwise modified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx